# How to send data from HTML form to Google Spreadsheet using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, google-sheets, google-apis-explorer

I'm trying to build a webapp that records datas from a form in a Google Spreadsheet. To do this, I **have** to use JavaScript (JSON or AJAX requests will work as well), but I **cannot** use Google Apps Script because I need the user to keep using my pages and GAS doesn't allow it.

I'm not so much versed in JSON requests but I tried to make an append one: no surprise, it's not working and no surprise, I don't know why.

I'm not sure the URL I used to make the request and the code are correct, but not knowing very well how to proceed, it's quite difficult to know what's wrong in my code.

That's my form:

```
    <form name="reqForm" id="reqForm" method="post" action="" accept-charset="UTF-8" enctype="application/json">
            <input type="hidden" name="area" id="area" readonly/>
            <input type="hidden" name="idN" id="idN" readonly/>
            <input type="hidden" name="dataReq" id="dataReq" readonly />
            <label for="nome">* Nome:</label>
            <input type="text" id="nome" name="nome" placeholder="Il tuo nome" />
            <label for="cognome">* Cognome:</label>
            <input type="text"  id="cognome" name="cognome" placeholder="Il tuo cognome" />
            <label for="mat">* Matricola:</label>
            <input type="text" id="mat" name="mat" placeholder="La tua matricola" />
            <label for="mail">* E-mail:</label>
            <input type="text" id="mail" name="mail" placeholder="La tua e-mail" />
            <label for="testo">* Richiesta:</label>
            <textarea id="testo" name="testo" placeholder="Che cosa vuoi chiedere?"></textarea>
            <button type="button" value="Invia" onClick="check()">Invia</button>
        </form>`
```

The hidden values are set to provide an ID Number and the user's path.

The `check()` function will check the form and (should) make the request and write in the GSpreadSheet

```
    function check() {

document.getElementById('errorForm').innerHTML = "";

var a = document.getElementById('area').value;
var idN = document.getElementById('idN').value;
var n = document.getElementById('nome').value;
var c = document.getElementById('cognome').value;
var m = document.getElementById('mat').value;
var em= document.getElementById('mail').value;
var t = document.getElementById('testo').value;

// check the possible errors and set error messages.
    // if msg is not empty, writes the messages in my page.

} else if(msg == "") {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var key = mySheetKey, sName =  mySheetName, url = "https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/"+key+"/values/"+ sName + ":append?valueInputOption=USER_ENTERED";

    xhr.open("POST", url, true);
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if(xhr.readyState === 4 && xhr.status === 200) {
            var json = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
        }
    // Here I should create the object made of my variables I read 
    // from my form at the beginning of the code and send the request that
    // should append my datas to my Spreadsheet

    xhr.send();
    } 
    }
```

As I said before, my code look similar to several ones I found online but it's not working and I don't know how to understand what's wrong.

Could you please kindly give me some tips or advice or some example that could help me **appending data to a Google Spreadsheet**?

Comment: Why on EARTH are you using XMLHttpRequest AND $.ajax - that is just silly. Also where is the if to the else?

Comment: follow the apis used for this purpose https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/append

Comment: @mplungjan I'm really sorry... This is new to me and I'm not versed in AJAX or XMLHttpRequest... could you please give me some tips or anything that could help me please?

Comment: @ChandanKumarThakur thanks for your reply: I read it several times but there's no samples and I can't understand how to write the code and the URL

Comment: No need to apologise. Your code is however a mess. You need to post a [mcve] - right now I see poor variable names, some in global scope and none of them used in the actual posting

Comment: here is a sample of writing into sheets: https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/samples/writing

Comment: @mplungjan I couldn't get how to create the object required and send it... I'm working on this code since last week and I read all about this kind of things but I just can't get it. I'm trying right now to make the code in my question look better but I don't know how far can I get...

Comment: I cannot salvage your code. It shows a complete lack of knowledge of how JavaScript works. For example all the vars in the beginning of the function are not used at all and all the code after the comment could be written as `var key = mySheetKey,
  sName = mySheetName,
  url = "https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/" + key + "/values/" + sName + 
  ":append?valueInputOption=USER_ENTERED";
$.post(url, function(data) {
  alert(data);
});
` - assuming that is the correct syntax for google sheets

Comment: @ChandanKumarThakur according to the last sample (appending values), could I add my variables in the "values" as described in the code? Where should I put it to be sure it will be submitted?

Comment: @mplungjan I know the var at the beginning are not used: I read them from my form and I should send them in the GSS but I don't know how... I can correct the code, but in this case I don't know how to set the object containing my vars and send them to the Ss

Comment: Here's a guide: https://dev.to/levinunnink/sending-data-from-a-html-form-to-a-google-sheet-3m42

Or use https://sheetmonkey.io for this. It's free and doesn't require any code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## A simple spreadsheet contained web app example

```
$(function() {
        $('#btn1').click(validate);
        $('#txt4').val('');
        $('#txt3').val('');
        $('#txt2').val('');
        $('#txt1').val('')
      });
function validate()
{
    var txt1 = document.getElementById('txt1').value || ' ';
    var txt2 = document.getElementById('txt2').value || ' ';
    var txt3 = document.getElementById('txt3').value || ' ';
    var txt4 = document.getElementById('txt4').value || ' ';
    var a = [txt1,txt2,txt3,txt4];
    if(txt1 && txt2 && txt3 && txt4)
    {
      google.script.run
        .withSuccessHandler(setResponse)
        .getData(a);
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
      alert('All fields must be completed.');
    }
}
```

The entire example:

The HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>
  <div id="data">
    <br />Text 1<input type="text" size="15" id="txt1" />
    <br />Text 2<input type="text" size="15" id="txt2" />
    <br />Text 3<input type="text" size="15" id="txt3" />
    <br />Text 4<input type="text" size="15" id="txt4" />
    <br /><input type="button" value="submit" id="btn1" />
  </div>
  <div id="resp" style="display:none;">
    <h1>Response</h1>
    <p>Your data has been received.</p>
  </div>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      $(function() {
        $('#btn1').click(validate);
        $('#txt4').val('');
        $('#txt3').val('');
        $('#txt2').val('');
        $('#txt1').val('')
      });

      function setResponse(a)
      {
        if(a)
        {
          $('#data').css('display','none');
          $('#resp').css('display','block');
        }
      }

      function validate()
      {
        var txt1 = document.getElementById('txt1').value || ' ';
        var txt2 = document.getElementById('txt2').value || ' ';
        var txt3 = document.getElementById('txt3').value || ' ';
        var txt4 = document.getElementById('txt4').value || ' ';
        var a = [txt1,txt2,txt3,txt4];
        if(txt1 && txt2 && txt3 && txt4)
        {
          google.script.run
            .withSuccessHandler(setResponse)
            .getData(a);
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
          alert('All fields must be completed.');
        }
      }

      function loadTxt(from,to)
      {
          document.getElementById(to).value = document.getElementById(from).value;
      }

     console.log('My Code');
   </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

The Apps Script:

```
function getData(a)
{
  var ts = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT-6", "yyyy-MM-dd' 'HH:mm:ss");
  a.push(ts);
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Login').appendRow(a);
  return true;
}

function doGet()
{
  var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('index');
  return html.setXFrameOptionsMode(HtmlService.XFrameOptionsMode.ALLOWALL)

}
```

My simple spreadsheet:

[image]

The good news is that you're probably a lot better at using the Google Chrome debugger now than before you started.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong: your code will send my data to a Google App Script that writes in my Spreadsheet?

Comment: The function getData(a) is in a gs file on the server.   This code comes from a simple web app.  It's sending an array of text values.

Comment: Yes it will send data from a web app to a script that is bound to my spreadsheet and it will append a line of new data each time.  Note: the entire html file has not been included.  It's true I'm not using a '<form' per se but the end result is that data moves from client to server and then back to client via the set response.

Comment: Do you want the entire example?

Comment: ok last question - I hope: I made several attempts with Google Apps Script using the URL of the script in the action of my form. My problem was that I could not "exit" from the frame the Script generated. Do you know if in this way, will I be able to run everything in my app/webapp pages? In any case, I really thank you for your reply, I'll make some attempts hoping it will fit. I'm very, very glad for your answer.

Comment: I can give you the entire example.  It runs.  I haven't had any problems with it.  It take four text inputs and populates a new row on my spreadsheet.

Comment: It would be just amazing! I made so many attempts and now I'm really confused about all this

Comment: By the way here is the answer to your question about [examples](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/communication). I read this several times before I made the connection and the very first line on the top of the page reads "google.script.run is an asynchronous client-side JavaScript API that allows HTML-service pages to call server-side Apps Script functions."  once I realized what it was telling me my whole scripting world changed.

Comment: Sometimes we who serve here try too hard to seem intelligent and often not hard enough just to be helpful.

Comment: Ok I'm trying to edit the code according to my needs. Just a quick quest: your HTML page is written in the Google Apps Script or it's "autonomous"?

Comment: Uhm something's wrong with my version of the code... It doesn't seem to work... I'll try to figure out why

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146961/discussion-between-cooper-and-simone).