# Google App Script and Html Form not communicating

Tags: ajax, google-apps-script

I need help with Google App Script on a Google Sheet and an Html form.  I just cannot get them to connect properly.  The form has  a text box and two buttons.  The user enters a name in the text box and press the start button.  The start button records time to a variable.  When finished, the user presses finish.  The finish button records the time and processes the text box and start button.  This info is sent back to the Google App Script to be written to the Sheet.  I would like to use an AJAX or JQuery call, but it doesn't seem to be working.  Need a little help getting the nice form working.  I have tried doGet(e) and doGet() functions, but those aren't working.  I have tried lots of different versions of the code.  This isn't my final html form, but it has the same point.  If I click the button, AJAX should return something to the Google App Script after processing.  New to Google App Scripting and need help.  Thanks!

code.gs

```
function doGet(e) {
var result = "";
try {
  result = "Hi" + e.queryString;
//should write to the spreadsheet the information here
} catch (f) {
result= "Error" + f.toString();
}

result=JSON.stringify({"result":result});
return ContentService
.createTextOutput( "(" + result + ")")
.setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JAVASCRIPT);   

}
//where does HtmlService.createHtmlOutput('index.html') go?
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<base target="_top">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>

// Make an AJAX call to Google Script
function callGoogleScript() {

var url = "https://script.google.com/macros/s/" my script id "/exec";
var data = { name: "Tom", city: "Nowhere" };

var request = jQuery.ajax({

url:url+encodeURIComponent(data),

  method: "GET",
  dataType: "jsonp"
});

}

// print the returned data
function ctrlq(e) {
console.log(e.result)
}

</script>
</head>
<body>
<button id="test" name="test" onclick="callGoogleScript()">Test</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Edit:  This is for a Web App.

Comment: Here is a [complete example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44601310/how-to-send-data-from-html-form-to-google-spreadsheet-using-javascript/44607932#44607932);

Comment: That was perfect.  Merged it together with my form and it works!  Thank you so much.

Comment: remember you can call any script from your HTML with google.script.run.functionname();