# Google Sheets/Scripts: Form responses (HTML sidebar) into sheet

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-api

All I want to do is have my sidebar process user entries and input them into a specified range in my sheet. Here's my code so far:

```
function onOpen(e) {
  var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutput()
      .setTitle('TITLE')
      .setContent('<label>Enter Search Term:  </label> <br /><input id="WCB#" name="WCB#" type="text" /><br /><label>Enter Start Date:  </label> <br /><input id="WCB#" name="WCB#" type="text" /><br /><label>Enter End Date:  </label> <br /><input id="WCB#" name="WCB#" type="text" /><br /><input type="button" value="Submit" google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(onSuccess) />');
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi() // Or DocumentApp or FormApp.
      .showSidebar(html);

}
```

Comment: The submit button should have an `onClick="google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(onSuccess).nameofScriptFunction()";` You need to add the onClick and the name of your Google Script Function.

Comment: Thank you very much. Please excuse my ignorance. But how do I tell my function to pull the data from my sidebar form and enter it into the specified range in my sheet? I can't seem to find instructions. Thank you.

Comment: you'll probably want to change the id's of the text boxes so that you can use either document.getElementById().value or $('#id").val() to get the values out of the text boxes.   I'd probably return them in an array to the scripts in one of .gs files.  Here's a link to a [complete example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44601310/how-to-send-data-from-html-form-to-google-spreadsheet-using-javascript/44607932#44607932).  It's not a sidebar but it could have been. If you wouldn't mind, I'd appreciate it if you'd check off my answer.  Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tend to do it like this.

```
function showMySideBar() 
{
  var s='Enter Search Term:';
  s+='<br /><input id="WCB#" name="WCB#" type="text" />';
  s+='<br />Enter Start Date:';
  s+='<br /><input id="WCB#" name="WCB#" type="text" />';
  s+='<br />Enter End Date:';
  s+='<br /><input id="WCB#" name="WCB#" type="text" />';
  s+='<br /><input type="button" value="Submit" onClick="google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(onSuccess).functionName();" />'
  var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(s).setTitle('TITLE');
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showSidebar(html);
}
```