# Google Sheets custom sidebar reload form on submit

Tags: jquery, html, forms, google-sheets, sidebar

I'm relatively new to Google Scripts and jQuery. Let's just say I probably know just enough to get myself into trouble! I am trying to create a custom UI sidebar for entering data to a Google Sheet. I used the code from this post as a starting point (Thank you to Cooper for sharing!!): [Cooper's Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44601310/how-to-send-data-from-html-form-to-google-spreadsheet-using-javascript/44607932#44607932)

Everything works beautifully, but I need to automatically reset the form after each submission so it's ready to accept the next entry. Ideally, I would like a confirmation dialog with a button to make a new entry. I modified the code as follows, but my "New Entry" button does nothing:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html>
          <head>
            <base target="_top">
          </head>
          <body>
          <div id="data">
            <br />Text 1<input type="text" size="15" id="txt1" />
    <br />Text 2<input type="text" size="15" id="txt2" />
    <br />Text 3<input type="text" size="15" id="txt3" />
    <br />Text 4<input type="text" size="15" id="txt4" />
    <br /><input type="button" value="Log Entry" id="btn1" />
  </div>
  <div id="resp" style="display:none;">
    <h1>Your data has been received.</h1>
    <input type="button" value="New Entry" id="btn2" />
  </div>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      $(function() {
        $('#btn1').click(validate);
        $('#btn2').click(openDialog);
        $('#txt4').val('');
        $('#txt3').val('');
        $('#txt2').val('');
        $('#txt1').val('')
      });

      function setResponse(a)
      {
        if(a)
        {
          $('#data').css('display','none');
          $('#resp').css('display','block');
        }
      }

      function validate()
      {
        var txt1 = document.getElementById('txt1').value || ' ';
        var txt2 = document.getElementById('txt2').value || ' ';
        var txt3 = document.getElementById('txt3').value || ' ';
        var txt4 = document.getElementById('txt4').value || ' ';
        var a = [txt1,txt2,txt3,txt4];
        if(txt1 && txt2 && txt3 && txt4)
        {
          google.script.run
            .withSuccessHandler(setResponse)
            .getData(a);
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
          alert('All fields must be completed.');
        }
      }

      function loadTxt(from,to)
      {
          document.getElementById(to).value = document.getElementById(from).value;
      }

     console.log('My Code');

     function openDialog() {
     var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile("index");
     html.setTitle('Gmf Sent Msg Form'); 
     SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showSidebar(html);
    }
   </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

I'm sure this is something simple that my newbie brain just isn't catching, but any help is appreciated!

Comment: HtmlService and SpreadsheetApp are server side not client side. You might want read [this](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/communication).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want your dialog to work you need to do something like this:

code.gs

```
function openMyDialog()
{
 var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile("index");
 html.setTitle('Gmf Sent Msg Form'); 
 SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showSidebar(html);
}
```

And in your javascript something like this:

```
function openDialog()
{
  google.script.run.openMyDialog();

}
```

Comment: This works wonderfully! I'm new, so I can't vote up, but would if I could.

Comment: You can check off the answer though.