# script not executing code after displaying input box in Google spreadsheet - How to run code after getting user input

Tags: html, google-apps-script, google-sheets, sidebar

Very new to coding & concepts.
This bit of code isn't what I want yet but it works well enough for the example.  It adds a incremental number to the next filled row.

```
    function onFormSubmit(e) {

var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
var row =  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getLastRow();

sheet.getRange(row,1).setValue(row);
}
```

This part adds a menu choice  PROCESS  and allows users to choose Next Order in the menu.  And I think I understand that I'm naming a custom function  nextOpenOrder to use next...

```
    function onOpen(e) {
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi()
      .createMenu('PROCESS')
      .addItem('Next Order', 'nextOpenOrder')
      .addToUi();
}
```

This then is my custom function which throws a browser box to prompt the user for the next order number as generated by the first bit of code.

```
    function nextOpenOrder() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var settingsSheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName('FormResponses3');
  settingsSheet.activate();
  var selectedRow = Browser.inputBox('Create Parts Order',
      'Please enter the Order ID# to use' +
      ' (for example, "2"):',
      Browser.Buttons.OK_CANCEL);
}
```

But the next step is to throw an html or pdf document. Eventual intent is to have a row's worth of data presented so the end user can enter a parts order in another piece of software.  I've figured out how to make a generic panel present itself.

```
function showDialog() {
  var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('INDEX')
      .setWidth(400)
      .setHeight(300);
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi() // Or DocumentApp or SlidesApp or FormApp.
      .showModalDialog(html, 'My custom dialog');
}
```

My INDEX.html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>
    Hello, World!    
  </body>
</html>
```

However the problem I can't seem to resolve is that this last bit of code doesn't execute on it's own.  I can run it from the script page and it will present a dialog box with the message.  But it doesn't happen automagically when I hit PROCESS and choose an order #.
Something simple I'm sure, since I'm really green at this.
Can someone push me forward?

Comment: You want `showDialog()` to run after you click OK from the input box?

Comment: Correct. Eventually what I want to happen is that they click OK and it will take a row of data out of the sheet and show it for processing.

Comment: You need to capture the return from the input box and then run some more code.  `if (selectedRow !== 'cancel') {showDialog();}`

Comment: Perfect  Thanks!

Comment: [Here's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44607932/7215091) an example for you to take a look at.  It's just a simple webapp which you can also run as a dialog.  It has javascript functions that communicate with the server functions  to read and write data to the spreadsheets.