# How to call a function from code.gs to run script in html on dialog open?

Tags: html, google-apps-script, web-applications

My Index.html has a  tag in which I am able to run the following code as I open the Modal Dialog on Google Sheets and it's called using the google.run

--Index.html--

```
<script>
function onSuccess(info) 
{
...add options to select tags...
}
function fillOtherMenus(info) 
{
...add options to other select tags...
}

google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(onSuccess).getDropdownMenus();
google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(fillOtherMenus).getOtherDropdownMenus();

</script>
```

At the moment this code works for the onSuccess function; however I cannot work out why it's not working for the fillOtherMenus function.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverFlow please take this opportunity to take the [tour] and learn how to [ask] and provide [mcve]. And if you receive an answer that helps you to resolve your problem please check it off so that everyone can see that the problem is resolved. Generally, we like to see the code that you have are having a problem with and a description of what you have tried. If you successfully integrate all of these suggestions into your question then your much more likely to get a quick resolution to your problem.

Comment: Javascript needs to be in `<script></script>` tags.

Comment: Yes, sorry about that, the functions are inside the script tags. It's my first question and was confused by what the question was looking like in the posting section; I've corrected it ;)

Comment: You should remove those `<br>` tags from inside the script tags.

Comment: True, I forgot to remove those in the last edit, thanks!

Comment: Here's a fairly simple example of [client to server communication](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44607932/7215091).

Comment: Ok, I understand what the example is showing. The click activates a function which in turn runs the google.run statement.

In my scenario I'm trying to run 2 functions once my Dialog opens. As mentioned, it works well with onSuccess function but not with fillOtherMenus function.

Comment: Look at the answer I provided.  It runs right after the DOM loads.

Comment: Yes, I do need it to load right after DOM loads. I don't quite get how I'm able to run onSuccess function but not fillOtherMenus function. In the provided answer you are running 'updateSelect' using a 'withSuccessHandler', would you be able to run another function right below that one by just writing say 'google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(fillOtherMenus).getMenus()' and adding a 'function getMenus() to your Code.gs file?

Comment: Sure let me modify the  script to do that.  Does that make sense?

Comment: This was one of the most important and empowering things to learn about google apps script.

Comment: Yah, I can see why. Thanks a lot!

Comment: If this answer solved your problem please check it.

Comment: Probably you have an issue with timing. Without seeing any of the code you're invoking, or an example of what your success handlers actually *do*, it's hard to say if there is even an issue. Simplest recommendation is absolutely to ensure the DOM has loaded before you try to execute functions that reference elements that may not yet properly exist.

Comment: [Mcve] is needed. Logs, handler codes and server code too. Have you attached `withFailureHandler()` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## An Example of Loading a Drop Down

Here's an example similar to what I think you're trying to accomplish...Loading a drop down list.  In this case, I load it right after the DOM loads.

```
<script>
  $(function(){
    $('#sel1').css('background-color','#ffff00');
    google.script.run
    .withSuccessHandler(function(vA){
       updateSelect(vA);
       anotherFunction();
     })
    .getTrackFiles();
  });
  function updateSelect(vA,id){
    $('#sel1').css('background-color','#ffffff');
    var id=id || 'sel1';
    var select = document.getElementById(id);
    select.options.length = 1; 
    for(var i=0;i<vA.length;i++)
    {
      select.options[i+1] = new Option(vA[i].name,vA[i].id);
    }
  }
....
</script>
```

Google Script:

```
function getTrackFiles() {
  var GPSTracksFolder=DriveApp.getFolderById(getGlobal('GPSTracksFolderId'));
  var tracks=GPSTracksFolder.getFiles();
  var files=[];
  while(tracks.hasNext()){
    var trackfile=tracks.next();
    files.push({name:trackfile.getName(),id:trackfile.getId()});
  }
  return files.sort(compareTrackFileNames);
}

function compareTrackFileNames(fa,fb) {
  var a=fa.name;
  var b=fb.name;
  Logger.log('FileName a: %s',a);
  Logger.log('a-0: %s, 1: %s, 2: %s, 3: %s, 4: %s, 5: %s, 6: %s',Number(a.slice(0,4)),Number(a.slice(5,7)-1),Number(a.slice(8,10)),Number(a.slice(11,13)),Number(a.slice(14,16)),Number(a.slice(17,19)),Number(a.slice(20,22))*10);
  Logger.log('FileName b: %s',b);
  Logger.log('b-0: %s, 1: %s, 2: %s, 3: %s, 4: %s, 5: %s, 6: %s',Number(b.slice(0,4)),Number(b.slice(5,7)-1),Number(b.slice(8,10)),Number(b.slice(11,13)),Number(b.slice(14,16)),Number(b.slice(17,19)),Number(b.slice(20,22))*10);
  var vA=new Date(Number(a.slice(0,4)),Number(a.slice(5,7)-1),Number(a.slice(8,10)),Number(a.slice(11,13)),Number(a.slice(14,16)),Number(a.slice(17,19)),Number(a.slice(20,22))*10).valueOf();
  var vB=new Date(Number(b.slice(0,4)),Number(b.slice(5,7)-1),Number(b.slice(8,10)),Number(b.slice(11,13)),Number(b.slice(14,16)),Number(b.slice(17,19)),Number(b.slice(20,22))*10).valueOf();
  Logger.log('vA: %s vB: %s vA-Vb: %s',vA,vB,vA-vB);
  Logger.log('**********************');
  return vB-vA;
}
```