# How to send value returned by gs function to html template?

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script, web-applications

I'm trying to create html template dependent on spreadsheet content. But since a week I'm stuck on sending values returned by GS function to html template. When I call function located in html , I get result that I expect. But when I call the same function located in gs.code file, I get undefined. What am I doing wrong?

This works, but is useless:

HTML file:

```
<script>
  function addOption() {
      var x = document.getElementById("xBad");
      var option = document.createElement("option");
      option.text = newOpt();
      x.add(option);
  };
  function newOpt() {
      var str = "extra option";
      return str;
  }
</script>
```

But when I replace function which returns extra option to gs file, where exactly I need it, it add undefined.

HTML file:

```
<script>
  function addOption() {
  var x = document.getElementById("xBad");
      var option = document.createElement("option");
      option.text = google.script.run.newOpt();
      x.add(option);
  }
</script>
```

GS file:

```
function newOpt() {
  var str = "extra option";
  return str;
}
```

I guess, I've read all the google API documentation about this and all the problems related to mine in stackoverflow, but I'm afraid, I cannot find an explanation. The only one answer, I understood suggest that google.script.run doesn't return values, until there no SuccessHandler put into the code, but I really don't know, what condition can be successful or failure in this case.

Comment: To call a Google Script Function from  Javascript use [google.script.run](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/run)

Comment: Take a look at this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44607932/7215091)

Comment: google.script.run.newOpt() run asynchronous so you need withSuccessHandler otherwise x.add will execute before newOpt() completes. And the way you have coded it nothing is returned. See withSuccessHandler

Answer (score 1):

Something like this might work for you:

```
<script>
  function addOption() {
      google.script.run
      .withSuccessHandler(function(txt){
        var x = document.getElementById("xBad");
        var option = document.createElement("option");
        option.text = txt;
        x.add(option);
      })
      .newOpt();
  }
</script>
```

Comment: First, newOpt() is called and if it returns something it is sent to the withSuccessHandler which is an anonymous function in this case and txt is filled with the value returned from newOpt(). It's all explained on [this page](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/communication).

Comment: Thank you Cooper. You helped me again. But I still don't understand, how it works. I simplify withSuccessHandler to condition which have to be fulfilled to run the command. I interpreted this like: withSuccessHandler(condition).effect. But in your code it looks rather like: withSuccessHandler(effect).condition. Is it better interpretation?

Comment: withSuccessHandler is not a condition to run newOpt() it just establishes the destination for the return which will happen sometime in the future.

Comment: And such explanation should be on "this page", for me to understand it. Thank you once again.

Comment: We have an expectation here that you already know JavaScript, based up the overview in the Google Apps Script documentation.  As it says in the overview, If you're new to JavaScript, Codecademy offers [a number of JavaScript courses](https://www.codecademy.com/catalog/language/javascript).  Perhaps, that's something you should look into.

Comment: According to your activity on this forum, I suspect you are the bot, but very helpful bot. The courses you recommended, look like exactly, what I need. Thanks.