# Grab value from class in deployed web app - Google App Script

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a simple html form on a webapp, in which the user can input information

```
<form>
Field 1: <input class="pod" type="text" name="Field1" value="Test1"><br>
Field 2: <input class="Start-Date" type="text" name="start-date" 
value="2019-03-29"><br>
</form>
```

Once the user inputs this information I simply need to grab it, which I can do on the HTML file through some jquery:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
var test = $(".pod").val();  
});
</script>
```

So this works on the HTML file. I can't however get this to work on the .gs file and I am lost on how to accomplish that. I need the user input to run SQL and return some data afterward. All documentation I found was rather confusing and didn't me help much, so I hope that somebody can help me here.

Alternatively: How can you use a variable defined on the HTML file on the GS file? For instance, what if I grabbed the information through the example code on the html file, is there a way to call this variable (var test) on the GS file?

Thank you a ton, 
Sascha

Comment: I have several simple examples of passing data from client and back from server.  Here's one https://stackoverflow.com/a/44607932/7215091

Comment: Also I recommend reading [this page](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/communication) over and over until you completely understand it.  It's the key ingredient to be able to run google scripts from clientside javascript.

Answer (score 0):

1. Grab your user input from frontend
2. Pass that to backend using [run](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/run#myFunction(...))
3. Execute your SQL in backend using the user inputs received.
4. Return the result from backend
5. Receive response from backend in frontend using [withsuccesshandlerfunction](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/run#withsuccesshandlerfunction)

Reference : [How to send data from HTML form to Google Spreadsheet using JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44601310/how-to-send-data-from-html-form-to-google-spreadsheet-using-javascript/44607932#44607932)